# Need advice to solve conflict between Content Approval and SPD Workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, content-approval

I have a list with "Require Content Approval" turned on. The list have 2 columns "IsExpire" and "Expire date". A SPD global reusable workflow is setup on the list to check whether the item reach its "expire date". On the expire date the item will be updated from IsExpire=False to IsExpire=True.

The problem is, the workflow will modify the item. The item approval status will become "pending" after modification. Hence the visitor permission users will not aware it is expired.

If I change the workflow logic to "approve" the item after changing, it cause another problem which "rejected" or "pending" item being approved by workflow un-willingly.

How can I work around it? Thank you.